# FadeOut content...load new content...FadeIN

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I want to FadeOut the current holder div, then load in the new content and fade it in.

Everything is working fine...content loads and fades In. I just don't know where and how to put the FadeOut part! So it Fades Out the current div, loads in the new content and then Fades that In!

Help?

```
$('.menu_home').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#pageContent').hide().load(href).fadeIn(2000);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why are you immediately closing your ready block?

Answer (score 3):

Use the callback from [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/):

```
$('#pageContent').fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $(this).load(href).fadeIn(2000);
})
```

Comment: Sir, you are the man! Thank you so much tymeJV !!  :)